# CorePlot: XAxis Text Labels with labelingPolicy conflict

Tags: ios5, text, core-plot, policy, labeling

Why labelingPolicy distinct of CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone don´t found in string labels???

```
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
```

[image]

I want this GRIDLineStyle, but with my text labels:

```
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval
```

[image]

I complete xAxisLabels with this code:

```
NSMutableArray *labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[labelsAxisX count]];
    int idx = 0;
    for (NSString *product in labelsAxisX)
    {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:product textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt(idx);
        label.offset = 5.0f;
        [labels addObject:label];
        [label release];
        idx++;
    }

    x.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:labels];
    [labels release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` labeling policy, you need to provide the tick locations (major and/or minor) in addition to making the labels. If you'd rather use the fixed interval labeling policy, you could make a custom number formatter for the axis that returns your text labels instead of numbers.

Here's an example adapted from the Labeling Policy Demo in the Plot Gallery example app:

```
NSMutableSet *tickLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
for ( NSUInteger loc = 0; loc < labelsAxisX.count; loc++ ) {
    [tickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:loc]];
}
axis.majorTickLocations = tickLocations;
```

Minor tick locations work the same way.

Comment: How?? I have modified my post with the code that i use to complete a array of labels.... but i dont know how solve my problem...

Comment: I wish to do similar: using a fixed-width policy reflecting variable data having customized labels.   In my case, months.  Each month could have variable # data; but I want the month intervals to be fixed (not variable as in manual policy).  How can I replace the fixed interval's numbers with NSStrings (per respective month)? <br/> Ref:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12631504/edit-submit/190af0df-e249-44bd-9490-5b46f826c905

Comment: You can implement the `-axis:shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations:` delegate method. Use the provided set of locations to make your custom labels.